# Big Sur on Macbook Pro M1 does not allow to add an Administrator account to a file

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur

So, I'm trying to install MPlayer X on my new M1 Macbook Pro (http://mplayerx.org/download.html), and I get the now classic "You don't have permissions to open this file" or the like.

Previously I had some issue with another file , I opened the '**Get Info**' Window, unlocked permissions and added the Administrator user besides my own user already added, and was able to run the file.

Now, I'm trying to do the same with the MPlayerX app to no avail. I already tried unsuccessfully the sudo upx -d path_to_app and the **xattr -d -r com. apple. quarantine**. I also tried c**hmod 777** etc, nothing.

Everytime that I tried to change the permissions for the users staff or everyone, from **Read only** to **Read & Write**, I get the 'The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission'

So it looks that even though that my own default account is an admin account, it doesn't have full permissions, it's not a real admin.

What could be a workaround of this? I tried booting, entering in recovery mode and creating a new Admin account, but it was not possible (**using rm /var/db/.applesetupdone**)

Other ideas?

Comment: How exactly are you installing MPlayerX? and what is the exact error message

Comment: I just run the dmg and when it mounts BigSur does not allow to drag it to Applications or to run it from there.

Comment: You can try if you have an M1, http://mplayerx.org/download.html

Comment: I won't try it - it runs an installer so who knows what it puts on my disk - I don't have a VM setup for testing malware

Comment: The download page does say that it is for OSX 10.7  and was updated last in 2016 So I would suggest it is unmaintained and they have not kept up with Apple's chnages - Unless their support has an answer I would look for a more modern app. I used to use this but replaced it 3-4 years by IINA

Comment: I agree, I will switch to IINA. However, the fact that is not possible to change the permissions or that the default admin account doesn't come with enough privileges still baffles me.

Comment: We would have to see the code for the installer

Comment: Missing from this is the location of the file of which you are trying to change the permissions.

Comment: Marc, the location of the file is inside the mounted dmg. I can't drag it to Applications because it tells me I don't have permissions to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same problem for some of my downloaded apps outside of the appstore .

Try this :

1. Press `command + space` and type `terminal` and press enter to open terminal
2. Paste this code in terminal and press enter .

`sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/app`

Note : to get the path to app simply drag the file you can't open because of permission issues to terminal .

`sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /path/to/app`

3. Next paste this code with the path of the app and press enter .

You can open the file now with no permission problems .